# How to create a large data frame in R with or without creating a matrix first and then converting it to a data.frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I need to create a matrix which has **80000 rows and 80000 columns**. But, after reading on Rbloggers, I got to know that, the number of elements in a matrix cannot exceed **2^31 - 1**. My plan to avoid this problem for my particular algorithm is to use a data frame instead of a matrix. Is there a way I can create an empty data frame of dimension 80000 x 80000 without first creating a matrix and then converting it to a data.frame using **as.data.frame** like below?

```
myMatrix <- matrix(0, ncol = 40, nrow = 90)
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(myMatrix)
```

Comment: Probably look into [`Matrix`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html)::[`sparseMatrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseMatrix.html).

Comment: I think it is very helpful for your purposes read read this paper about the `bigmemory` package. http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/temp/bigmemory-vignette.pdf

Comment: The limit of 2^31 - 1 on vectors is only for R versions earlier than 3.0.0, isn't it? I had no problem with `x = matrix(0, nrow=80000, ncol=80000)` if that's what you need.

Comment: @ping My R Version is 3.2.0 and I am not getting the error when trying to create just a matrix. Here I am using a package FNN and function knn.index to generate the neighbors (For example, if I have 80,000 rows in my dataset, I want to see 79,999 neighbors). When I do that the function returns the error message  "long vectors (argument 6) are not supported in .Fortran".

Comment: @josilber Interesting, I don't really ever need to use vectors that large so have never really done much with them. I've noticed that while `x[1, 1]` fails, `x[ ,1]` , `x[1, ]` and `x[[1, 1]]` don't... presumably support for large vectors is still not universal even in base R?

Answer (score 4):

You could construct an empty data frame of size 80,000 x 80,000 as follows:

```
dat <- do.call(data.frame, replicate(80000, rep(FALSE, 80000), simplify=FALSE))
dim(dat)
# [1] 80000 80000
dat[1,1]
# [1] FALSE
dat[80000,80000]
# [1] FALSE
```

Basically you build a list containing each column of the data frame you want to build (I built the list with `replicate` with `simplify=FALSE`) and then you build a data frame out of this with `do.call` and the `data.frame` function.

A few notes:

1. You'd better have several dozen gigabytes of memory to have a chance of fitting this into your computer's memory (my R process shows 48 GB of allocated memory).
2. This will be much slower than matrix allocation; for the 8000 x 8000 case the data frame construction took 36 seconds and the matrix construction took 1 second. It took 54 minutes for the data full data frame to allocate.
3. If your data is sparse, this is a wasteful option and you should use a sparse matrix.

Though allocating a matrix of this size did not fail at allocation in 64-bit linux (R version 3.2.0), basic operations don't appear to work:

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow=80000, ncol=80000)
dim(x)
# [1] 80000 80000
x[1,1]
# Error: long vectors not supported yet: subset.c:733
```

Comment: Thanks @josilber. I do have enough memory I suppose and no my data is not sparse.

Comment: Thanks josilber and ping.  I am able to create that matrix on my cluster individually. But, when I use the  package for some odd reasons is not able to. I am here using the FNN package and knn.index  function to genrate 79,999 neighbors for the dataset having 80,000 rows

Comment: or `data.frame(replicate(8e4, logical(8e4), simplify=FALSE))` (+1)

Comment: The rule that seems to apply is 3 times the RAM of the largest object.